# Fresh install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS - No dash

Tags: gnome-shell

I just made a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 and the "dash" or "panel" on the left side is missing. It is totally missing.

I did not even have the time to change any config or install anything, so wondering why is missing.
I checked however in the appearance settings, there is no auto-hide enabled. If I go to the "activities view" I can see all the open windows and then a small dash appears correctly.

Any ideas?